# Rat turda in gravel

Tags: gravel, vacuum

Rat droppings in Gravel

I had a rat problem :( they used the gravel in my crawl space as a litter box. I could ozone everything and use a hepa filtration to clean the air but I am worried that I need to get the turds out of the gravel. Custom shop vac tip with duct tape? ( cover intake on hose with duct tape and stab a bunch of rat pop sized holes in it) Thank you for any ideas!

Comment: Why are you worried that you need to remove the turda? Anything you do yourself to get them out of the gravel is only going to disturb them, exciting minute portions of them into the air. Especially the shop vac, even if it really does have an HEPA filter, as HEPA filters will not remove all viruses.

Comment: how big is the crawl space?  a picture of the space would help with possible options.  crawl spaces can be nasty.  removal sounds like the wrong option.

Comment: Disinfect the place.